# Unable to initialize vector from initializer list in delegating constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++17, initializer-list

I have a class `MyClass` as follows:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(vector<vector<float>> arg) {
       // some code here
    }
    MyClass(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>> arg)
        : MyClass(vector<vector<float>>(arg)) {
    }
    // other class members
};
```

I'm trying to use a delegating constructor above, as I want an instance of `MyClass` to be constructed from both `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>>` and `vector<vector<float>>` types, and the constructor code blocks are identical. So I'm trying to delegate the construction of the nested initializer lists by initializing a multidimensional vector and using its constructor.

However, the above code gives me a compiler error:

```
no instance of constructor "std::__1::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::vector [with _Tp=std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float>>, _Allocator=std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float>>>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>>)
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-9.3.0/include/c++/9.3.0/vector:67,
                 from prog.cc:11:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-9.3.0/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/stl_vector.h:622:7: note: candidate: 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::initializer_list<_Tp>, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<float>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<float> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::vector<float> >]'
  622 |       vector(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
      |       ^~~~~~
/opt/wandbox/gcc-9.3.0/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/stl_vector.h:622:43: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>>' to 'initializer_list<std::vector<float>>'
  622 |       vector(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: perhaps mention your previous question. context is always good

Comment: I've added notes following that error, which explain why it fails, but those are from a different compiler and might be not matching your output. Feel free to rollback my edit if it's conflicting with your own error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initializer_list constructor for `std::vector` looks like:

```cpp
vector(std::initializer_list<value_type>)
```

Where `value_type` is the first template argument to `std::vector`. In this case, `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` has `value_type = std::vector<float>` -- which means that it can only be constructed from a `std::initializer_list<std::vector<float>>` directly.

In order for this to work, you will need to update in one of the following ways:

1. update your `std::initializer_list` to be `std::initializer_list<std::vector<float>>`,
2. just use the `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` constructor and ignore using the `initializer_list` entirely<sup>1</sup>, or
3. Range construct from the `initializer_list<initializer_list<float>>` in the constructor`:

   ```cpp
   MyClass(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>> arg)
       : vec{arg.begin(), arg.end()} 
   {
       // each iterator points to an initializer_list, which implicitly
       // constructs each vector
   }
   ```

   **Edit:** Since this question is asking with respect to *delegating constructors*, you would be stuck explicitly constructing a temporary vector-of-vectors first:

   ```cpp
   MyClass(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>> arg)
     : MyClass{std::vector<std::vector<float>>{arg.begin(), arg.end()}}
   ```

   This is a case where delegating constructors probably aren't the best solution to your problem. See below.

---

<sup>1</sup> Since `std::vector` already works properly with initializer lists, even when nested in other types, it would probably be easiest to just ignore adding an explicit `std::initializer_list` constructor entirely -- and just use move semantics properly in the implementation.

If you're using `std::move` properly, this constructor should be relatively cheap anyway -- which could make the initializer list functionality come for free.

Comment: You can do better in (3), since `vector<T>` is constructible from an iterator pair: `vec(arg.begin(), arg.end())` does exactly your loop for you

Comment: `vector::emplace_back` with a `std::initializer_list` should be equivalent to contiguous iterator range-based construction, since the size is known up-front and the range is immutable in both cases.

Comment: Sure, but why would you manually write the whole thing out when you don't have to?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you were proposing. Good suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @Human-Compiler I don't think I fully understand method (3), so please bear with me: after `vec` is constructed, how do I use it to initialize an instance of `MyClass`? I'd have to place `MyClass(vec)` in the delegating constructor, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Comment: I missed that your question explicitly was asking about delegating constructors. The only way to do this would be to explicitly construct a [temporary vector-of-vectors and pass it to the delegating constructor](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4fTrYf). This is a case where delegating constructors are really not the best solution to your problem. It would be cleaner to construct the vector member directly -- or to just not have an `initializer_list` overload, which will be effectively equivalent

Comment: Ah, I see! I don't think I can avoid delegating constructors (without relying on template machinery) since both constructors have identical code, and I wish to avoid code duplication. Thank you for taking the time to write this answer. This has been immensely helpful for an absolute beginner like me.

Answer (score 1):

You need vector of `floats` in `std::initializer_list`;

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
class MyClass{
        public:
            MyClass(vector<vector<float>> arg ): vec( arg) {
                // some code here
            }
            MyClass(std::initializer_list<std::vector<float>> arg) 
            : vec( arg ) {}; 
            
            // other class members

        private:
            std::vector<vector<float>> vec;
};
```

Comment: This is no longer a delegation, is it?